# Forward request to a non @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, forwarding

Is it possible to use `forward:/` syntax to redirect a request to a non `@RequestMapping` annotated method.

What I'm trying to achieve is a way to internally redirect a request to a path that can not be accessed directly from the browser.

For example, if the user requests `/image.jpg`, I'd like to redirect it to a controller that would answer for images, mapped to `/img/image.jpg`. The point is that `/img/image.jpg` cannot be accessed directly through the browser.

Is it possible? How could I achieve this necessity?

Comment: that is the basic idea of spring MVC's view resolver.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to redirect it to the file itself. I need to redirect the request to another controller method that have business logic and resolves a view. Did I missed your point?

Answer (score 1):

I think You need to create request mapping path if you want to use `forward:/` to call the resource. However you can achieve this by:

Create a request mapping path that is not accessible by end-user direct browser calls. Before forwarding the request for path put some extra request parameters those are check by request mapper then.

Example :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/direct/browser/call")
public String connections(WebRequest request) throws SQLException {
    //validate request
    request.setAttribute("formButton", isPost, WebRequest.SCOPE_REQUEST);
    return "redirect:/some/value";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/some/value")
public String connections(WebRequest request) throws SQLException {
    //validate request
    if(request.getParameter("formButton")!=null) { return "/homepage"; }
    // else : do processing
}
```

You can also restrict browser `HTTP GET` calls in your request mappings. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/value", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

HTTP Methods : HEAD, PUT, DELETE, TRACE and OPTIONS are also useful in your case.

Comment: Thanks. This would really be a security layer. But I don't want to prevent direct access for security reasons, but for architectural reasons. I'm still looking for a way to make a internal redirection to a non public controller.